# JAVA How to change variable value to zero each time it loops back

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, repeat

im using for loops to ask user to input item to buy and calculate the price...then it will ask whether the user will continue add another item...so its a loop again...then when the user stop the purchase...then it will calculate the totalprice...so im using:

```
    totalprice+=total;
```

but when the outer for loops will repeat for the second customer...the value of totalprice is still the value of purchase from first customer so it will add up...is there anyway i can revert totalprice value to 0 everytime it loop for the second customer?

this is my code for that method

```
public static void makeOrder() {
    for (index = 0; index < date.length; index++) {
        double price = 0;
        int order;
        char addOrder;
        String resume;
        System.out.print("\nCustomer" + (index + 1));
        System.out.print("\nEnter your name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the date of reservation(DD/MM/YY): ");
        date[index] = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your type of table(Couple/Family): ");
        String table = input.nextLine();
        do {
            System.out.println("BERKAT RESTAURANT MENU:\n\n MEALS \n1-Beef      Bolognese: RM17.00\n2-Chicken Marsala: RM 13.00\n3-Spaghetti Carbonara: RM  9.00\n4-Fillet Mignon: RM12.00");
            System.out.println("\nDRINKS \n5-Strawberry Fruit Punch: RM6.00 \n6-Vanilla Smoothies: RM 7.00\n7-Sky Juice: RM 3.00");
            System.out.print("\nEnter your choice of meals/drink: ");
            order = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the quantity: ");
            int quantity = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Do you want to add order?(Y/N): ");
            addOrder = input.next().charAt(0);

            double total = calculatePrice(order, quantity);

            subtotal += total;

        } while (addOrder != 'N');

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        System.out.printf("The total price you have to pay is: RM%6.2f ", subtotal);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Thank you for coming to our restaurant, Please come again!");
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");

    }
}// makeOrder method
```

i want to revert the subtotal value back to 0.00 everytime the 'for' loops back

Comment: It would help to see some more of your code so we can get an idea of what you need help with.

Comment: You mean like `totalprice = 0;`?

Comment: Please include your code, as it makes it easier for the community to help.

Comment: sorry about that...i edit the question back...

Comment: Where is subtotal declared?  You're dealing with scoping rules here, so we can't answer this definitively without the location of the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that you initialize `subtotal` to 0 at the start of your outside for loop.  This way for each customer, it is always 0, regardless of the number of items added to the order.

```
public static void makeOrder() {
  double subtotal = 0;
  for(index = 0, index < date.length; index++) {
    subtotal = 0;
    /* your other code here */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `subtotal` to 0 at the start of your for loop.

```
public static void makeOrder()
{
  for(index=0;index<date.length;index++)
  {
    double subtotal=0;
    double price=0;
    int order;
    char addOrder;
    String resume;
    System.out.print("\nCustomer"+(index+1));
    System.out.print("\nEnter your name: ");
    String name=input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the date of reservation(DD/MM/YY): ");
    date[index]=input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your type of table(Couple/Family): ");
    String table=input.nextLine();
    do{
      System.out.println("BERKAT RESTAURANT MENU:\n\n MEALS \n1-Beef      Bolognese: RM17.00\n2-Chicken Marsala: RM 13.00\n3-Spaghetti Carbonara: RM  9.00\n4-Fillet Mignon: RM12.00");
      System.out.println("\nDRINKS \n5-Strawberry Fruit Punch: RM6.00 \n6-Vanilla Smoothies: RM 7.00\n7-Sky Juice: RM 3.00");
      System.out.print("\nEnter your choice of meals/drink: ");
      order=input.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter the quantity: ");
      int quantity=input.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Do you want to add order?(Y/N): ");
      addOrder=input.next().charAt(0);

      double total=calculatePrice(order,quantity);

      subtotal+=total;

    }while(addOrder!='N');

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    System.out.printf("The total price you have to pay is: RM%6.2f ",subtotal);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Thank you for coming to our restaurant, Please come again!");
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");

  }
}//makeOrder method
```

Answer (score -1):

thank you guys for your help...so i declare subtotal=0.00 and it work like a charm

```
   public static void makeOrder()
  {
  for(index=0;index<date.length;index++)
  {
  double price=0;
  double subtotal=0.00;
  int order;
  char addOrder;
  String resume;
     System.out.print("\nCustomer"+(index+1));
     System.out.print("\nEnter your name: ");
     String name=input.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Enter the date of reservation(DD/MM/YY): ");
     date[index]=input.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Enter your type of table(Couple/Family): ");
     String table=input.nextLine();
     do{
     System.out.println("BERKAT RESTAURANT MENU:\n\n MEALS \n1-Beef Bolognese: RM17.00\n2-Chicken Marsala: RM 13.00\n3-Spaghetti Carbonara: RM 9.00\n4-Fillet Mignon: RM12.00");
     System.out.println("\nDRINKS \n5-Strawberry Fruit Punch: RM6.00 \n6-Vanilla Smoothies: RM 7.00\n7-Sky Juice: RM 3.00");
     System.out.print("\nEnter your choice of meals/drink: ");
     order=input.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Enter the quantity: ");
     int quantity=input.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Do you want to add order?(Y/N): ");
     addOrder=input.next().charAt(0);

     double total=calculatePrice(order,quantity);

     subtotal+=total;

     }while(addOrder!='N');

     System.out.println("");

  System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
  System.out.printf("The total price you have to pay is: RM%6.2f ",subtotal);
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Thank you for coming to our restaurant, Please come again!");
  System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");


     }
     }//makeOrder method
```